# What is the Best Way to get Installation Prefix in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am compiling my stuff both for Linux and Windows. On Linux, normally, the installation prefix is determined at compile time so everything can be hard-coded in the executables. On Windows, I use the standard MSVC install shield program and it allows the user to change the installation location. My question is what is the "correct/proper" way for the Windows port of a program to determine this installation prefix. Do I find the location of the executable and then subtract the installation prefix? Or, is there something in the registry during installation which tells me where I can find my data files/etc.?

Answer (score 2):

While you COULD use the registry (provided your installation sets an appropiate key, either automatically or because you told it to), I prefer just asking the program itself. Call the [`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with a `NULL` parameter to get the path for the executable.